# Using TeX for hyphenation only

Tags: hyphenation

I'd like to use TeX to hyphenate paragraphs of text--and only to hyphenate. My goal is to show hyphenated text on a webpage, with `&shy;` entities where a possible word break could happen.

So I'd like to get contents of an hbox of a paragraph after hyphenation in some machine-parseable format.

I could firstly put my paragraph into a box register, e.g. with `\setbox42=\hbox{Hyphenate me please}`, then I force the hyphenation algorithm to do its job (how?), then I show the contents of page with `\showlists`.

I have read the TeXbook, but I don't know how to force hyphenation to happen.

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess LuaTeX might be helpful here.

Comment: Have you seen [hyphenator.js](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/)? It uses the same patterns as TeX to hyphenate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command

```
\showhyphens{Hyphenate me please}
```

will produce

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 20--20
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Hy-phen-ate me please
```

in the .log file.

Comment: This one will show normal hyphens and discretionary ones in the same way, so that I won't be able to distinguish between them. Still, it might be good enough. Thanks!

Comment: not so fast -- if a word contains a discretionary hyphen (equivalent to `&shy;`), all other possible hyphenation points are ignored by tex.  so you don't get both shown the same way with `\showhyphens`.  maybe someone working with german conventions has come up with an alternate method in an extended tex, but not with the original tex program.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same idea once and started writing it up into a package to output html and PDF from the same input file... But I ran out of time to finish it. In fact, I'm not even sure what state it was in when I left it; the code is here: https://github.com/wspr/miter

In short, the idea is to use the soul package to determine where the hyphenation points are. This uses a similar idea to \showhyphens but is rather more flexible.

Let me know if you manage to get anything working from all this; I'd be interested to see the results.